# NetSuite SSCC Generation

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, restlet

All,

This has to do with SSCC barcoding and sequencing. We are setting up 3 custom records that will control the structure.

- Prefix - Example - (00)
- GS1 - Company Number
- Serialization Number

We are building an high-speed operation that is based on contracts and forecasts. Everything is to Stock (DC). I have to generate an SSCC barcode for every pallet that leaves our plant, and our DC transmit which SSCC goes to which order or reporting for Lot Traceability.

My API will generate/lookup/verify the SSCC number by SUB, based on the below.

- MES/Scata
- 3PL Warehousing
- Initial Pallet Generation at Plant

My Question is of the following.......

Due to High Speed of Transactions agains a Multiple Customer Record to control the SEQ for SSCC serialization. How does Netsuite handle requests to a RESTlet? Will Request send and wait for response? Are they multi-thread/queued? I need to understand that I can't assign a pallet with an existing SEQ. CanNetsuite accept 2 requests and return the same value based on the time of submission?